# XML not pulling in results

Tags: javascript, xml, wsdl

I'm trying to get results via xml based on input from the user.

It keeps returning "No results" even though there should be results. I have an eery feeling I've just overlooked or missed something.

It should work by a user inputting text and it autosuggests address details.

Any suggestions? I've tried debugging and have set alerts and all but still no luck.

```
    <input id="search" />
    <div id="l-s">
        <ul>

        </ul>
    </div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#l-s li").on("click", function(){
            var val = $(this);
            if(val.attr("adid")){
                window.location.href = "http://map.mywebsite.com/address?addressId="+val.attr("adid")+"&view=data";
            }
        });


        $("#search").on("keypress", function(){

            var _search = $("#search").val();
            var _pc = "";
            var _area = "";

            var toSend = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:x="x">'+
   '<soapenv:Header/>'+
   '<soapenv:Body>'+
      '<x:getLocalities soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">'+
         '<address xsi:type="xsd:string">'+_area+'</address>'+
         '<state xsi:type="xsd:string"></state>'+
         '<postcode xsi:type="xsd:string">'+_pc+'</postcode>'+
      '</x:getLocalities>'+
   '</soapenv:Body>'+
'</soapenv:Envelope>';

            if(_search.length >= 2){
                if(!isNaN(_search)){
                    _pc = _search;  
                }else{
                    _area = _search;    
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://map.mywebsite.com/service",
                    contentType: "text/xml",
                    dataType:"xml",
                    data:toSend,
                    success:function(output){
                        suggestions(output);
                    },
                    error:function(output){
                        suggestions(null);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    function suggestions(input){
        alert("Called");
        var px = $.parseXML(input);
        var xml = $(px);
        var result = xml.find("Result").children('i');

        if(result.length == 0){
            $("#l-s ul").html("<li>No results</li>");
        }else{
            var results = '';
            $.each(result, function(key, value){
                var l = $(value);
                var address = l.find("address").text();
                var state = l.find("state").text();
                var postCode = l.find("postcode").text();
                var code = l.find("addressId").text();
                results = results + '\n' + '<li adid="'+code+'">'+address + ", "+state+" "+postCode+'</li>';
            });
            $("#l-s ul").html(results);
        }
        $("#l-s").css("display", "inline");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it looks like you want the search to either be a postcode or an address based on whether it's a number or not. You want to leave the other field empty.

Not sure how much you've messed with the code before putting it on here. There's something a little off about `toSend`. It is constructed when `_area` and `_pc` are empty strings, and it's never updated again. I would move the `toSend` definition to right before `$.ajax`.

Comment: Still no luck :( I've tried many different things before putting it on here especially debugging the crap out of it.

Comment: @DT.DTDG is there an error message? Your code discards any error messages.